# Content Font in UIWebView

Tags: iphone

in my app im making use of UIWebView to load html page.When i change orientation from potrait to landscape mode content font changes it increases.If i tap on any of link the new request loaded in lanscape mode content font wont change.How to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Does the font size change because of automatic zooming? That's what happens in web browser, at least. Maybe you got same "feature" by default in UIWebView, too?

Comment: No there is no automatic zooming.I hvnt set any feature for UIWebView by default.